# Every window is white when I take a screenshot

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, memory, screen-capture

When I take a screenshot all pages and desktop items are white as the image below show.

[image]

Launchctl dump: https://pastebin.com/em1K05Py

But when I go to safe mode it works!

Specs:

- MacBook Pro (17-inch, Mid 2010)
- 2,53 GHz Intel Core i5
- 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
- Intel HD Graphics 288 MB
- High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G11023)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are there any applications running like Netflix or DVD player where protected DRM content would be potentially visible?

Comment: No, i don't have any DRM protected content open or visible.

Comment: Have you rebuilding the font cache on your mac?

Comment: I rebuild the font cache with this commands and restarted, but the problem continues. 

`sudo atsutil databases -remove`

`atsutil server -shutdown`

`atsutil server -ping`

Comment: Can you try this in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting)?

Comment: In Safe Mode works perfectly, but in when i go to the normal mode the problem continues.